# How to permanently switch of KDE Power Management warning about battery recall

Tags: kubuntu, power-management, battery, thinkpad, lenovo

I have Kubuntu 12.04 installed. Each time I boot I receive a notification that the battery I am using has been recalled. This is not actually the case, as the recall doesn't apply to T61 model of Thinkpad. The message looks like this:

[image: battery recall notification]

I would like to permanently dismiss this notification.

I have tried:

- copying `/lib/udev/rules.d/95-upower-battery-recall-lenovo.rules` to `/lib/udev/rules.d/96-upower-battery-recall-lenovo.rules` and modifying some of the logic in there. Note the higher number, intended to take priority over rule in `/lib/udev`, but it doesn't appear to.
- modified "/apps/gnome-power-manager/notify/perhaps_recall" property to be unchecked using `gconf-editor`

How do I get rid of this annoying warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 days ago i installed KDE Plasma Desktop on top of Ubuntu 12.04 and i get similar warnings(for Toshiba notebook). I could not find any solution except this:

Go Settings > System Settings > Power Management

Under "Power Management", click Advanced Settings > Configure Notifications

Then uncheck "Play a sound" and "Show a message in a popup" options for "Broken Battery(or something similar to this; i translated from Turkish, it might be different.)" notification.

I just found this solution and tested twice(once by logging off and once by restarting); notification was gone.

And please consider: This probably is not a right way to get rid of this wrong and annoying notification.

Hope this helps.